# Remove Time from date field in Teradata

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

Im trying to remove the time portion of a date field I am pulling in. I am using Teradata. I tried

`select cast(inv_dt as date) as invoice 
      from tablex`

to no avail it still is showing 09/01/2015 12:00:00 AM
I dont want to cast it as a char as I need to use the field in a calculation for dates. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your `cast(inv_dt as date)` does exactly what you want, you can use it in your *calculation for dates*...

If it's still showing a time portion it's due to your client (maybe it assumes Teradata's `DATE` is similar to Oracle's including time).

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

`select 
cast(cast(inv.INV_DT- EXTRACT(DAY FROM inv.INV_DT) + 1 as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') as char (10)) as inv_dt
from invoice inv`